# Error java.util.nosuchelementexception while using arrays?

Tags: java, arrays

For my program I am to separate positive and negative numbers from a data file using arrays. I am able to compile the program but when I run the main I get the error java.util.nosuchelementexception. I'm not really sure where the error is occurring and why I am receiving it. Some help is greatly appreciated.

Here is the program

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class Prog404aAP
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    //declares variables and arrays;
    int[] pos = new int [13];
    int[] neg = new int [13];
    int newFile; 

    //sets up kbrader
    Scanner kbReader=new Scanner(System.in); 

    //sets up scanner
    Scanner inFile = null;

    //input for 1st set of data
     try
    {
        inFile = new Scanner(new File("prog404a1.dat"));
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println("File not found!");
        System.exit(0);
    }


    System.out.println("Run File? 1 for yes 2 for no. Only 2 files are available to run");
    int decision = kbReader.nextInt();

    while( decision == 1 )
    {

    //header 
    System.out.println("Positive \t Negative");


    //stores the numbers from the file into both arrays depending on value
    for(int index = 0; index < 13; index++)
    {
        if(inFile.nextInt() < 0)
        {
           pos[index] = inFile.nextInt(); 
        }
        else
        {
            neg[index] = inFile.nextInt();
        }
    }

        //for loop for formatted output
        for(int index = 0; index < 13; index++)
        {
            System.out.println( pos[index] +"\t  " +neg[index]);

        }

    System.out.println("Run File? 1 for yes 2 for no. Only 2 files are available to run");
    newFile = kbReader.nextInt();

    if(newFile == 1)
    {
        decision = 1;
        //sets up scanner 
    inFile = null;

    //input for 2nd set of data
     try
    {
        inFile = new Scanner(new File("prog404a2.dat"));
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println("File not found!");
        System.exit(0);
    }

}
else
{
    decision = 2;
}

}
}
}
```

Here is my data file prog404a1

```
3
66
54
-8
22
-16
-56
19
21
34
-34
-22
-55
-3
-55
-76
64
55
9
39
54
33
-45
```

Here is my data file for prog404a2

```
 51
-66
-54
-22
-19
8
10
56
34
22
55
3
55
76
45
-21
-34
-64
-55
-9
-89
-54
-3
32
45
-25
```

Stack trace

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
at Prog404aAP.main(Prog404aAP.java:56)
```

Comment: Paste your entire stack trace

Comment: Post (add to your question) the entire exception including stack trace.

Comment: Shooting from the hip here, Scanner's nextInt method throws a NoSuchElementException when the source is exhausted: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()

Comment: `nextInt()` actually consumes the input, even the one inside your `if` statement.

Comment: @PM77-1 Stack trace has now been added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(int index = 0; index < 13; index++)
{
    if(inFile.nextInt() < 0)
    {
       pos[index] = inFile.nextInt(); 
    }
    else
    {
        neg[index] = inFile.nextInt();
    }
}
```

You're calling `nextInt()` twice for each value. When reaching the 7th element, you're actually trying to read the 14th element which doesn't exist and results into this exception. You need to put the value into a variable:

```
for(int index = 0; index < 13; index++)
{
    int nextVal = inFile.nextInt();
    if(nextVal  < 0)
    {
       pos[index] = nextVal ; 
    }
    else
    {
        neg[index] = nextVal ;
    }
}
```

Comment: And if you want to be absolutely safe add `if (inFile.has.NexInt())`.

Comment: @PM77-1: `if (inFile.has.NexInt())` throws the java.lang.Error.

Comment: This did the trick! I also had a few errors in the algorithm that I was able to fix because of this as well so thank you

Comment: Should be `if (inFile.hasNexInt())`

Answer (score 0):

Actually your file "prog404a1.dat" contains 23 elements and you're calling `inFile.nextInt()` twice which basically tries to read 24th line in your file when index = 12 and there is no 24th element in file. So it throws noSuchElementException.

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you my soulution. I think that you could use standard Java command to read whole files to a collection of string, instead of doing it manually. And unify methods for splitting and printing numbers:

```
public class Prog404aAP {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            System.out.println("Run File? 1 for yes 2 for no. Only 2 files are available to run");

            if (scan.nextInt() == 1) {
                print(Paths.get("prog404a1.dat"));
                System.out.println();
                print(Paths.get("prog404a2.dat"));
            }
        }
    }

    private static void print(Path path) {
        try {
            List<String> values = Files.readAllLines(path);
            int[] pos = values.stream().mapToInt(str -> Integer.parseInt(str.trim())).filter(i -> i >= 0).toArray();
            int[] neg = values.stream().mapToInt(str -> Integer.parseInt(str.trim())).filter(i -> i < 0).toArray();

            System.out.println("Positive\tNegative");

            for (int i = 0, max = Math.max(pos.length, neg.length); i < max; i++) {
                String p = i < pos.length ? String.valueOf(pos[i]) : "\t";
                String n = i < neg.length ? String.valueOf(neg[i]) : "\t";
                System.out.println(p + "\t\t\t" + n);
            }
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```